# Getting the user id from a database trigger in Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In the example below, is there a way to get the uid of the user who wrote to /messages/{pushId}/original?

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
.onWrite(event => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const original = event.data.val();
  console.log('Uppercasing', event.params.pushId, original);
  const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
  // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
  // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
  // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
  return event.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ever since Firebase functions reached version 1.0, this behavior is no longer undocumented but has sligtly changed. Be sure to read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).

Context has been added to cloud functions and you can use it like this

```
  exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path/with/{id}').onWrite((data, context) => {
  const authVar = context.auth; // Auth information for the user.
  const authType = context.authType; // Permissions level for the user.
  const pathId = context.params.id; // The ID in the Path.
  const eventId = context.eventId; // A unique event ID.
  const timestamp = context.timestamp; // The timestamp at which the event happened.
  const eventType = context.eventType; // The type of the event that triggered this function.
  const resource = context.resource; // The resource which triggered the event.
  // ...
});
```

Comment: This feature has seemingly disappeared again in Version 2.0 of Cloud Functions

Answer (score 51):

**UPDATED ANSWER (v1.0.0+)**:

As noted in [@Bery's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796385/2955366), version `1.0.0` of the Firebase Functions SDK introduced a new [`context.auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#.auth) object which contains the authentication state such as `uid`. See ["New properties for user auth information"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database) for more details.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (pre v1.0.0):**

Yes, this is technically possible, although it is not currently documented. The `uid` is stored with the `event.auth` object. When a Database Cloud Function is triggered from an admin situation (for example, from the Firebase Console data viewer or from an Admin SDK), the value of `event.auth` is:

```
{
  "admin": true
}
```

When a Database Cloud Function is triggered from an unauthenticated reference, the value of `event.data` is:

```
{
  "admin": false
}
```

And finally, when a Database Cloud Function is triggered from an authed, but not admin, reference, the format of `event.auth` is:

```
{
  "admin": false,
  "variable": {
    "provider": "<PROVIDER>",
    "provider_id": "<PROVIDER>",
    "user_id": "<UID>",
    "token": {
      // Decoded auth token claims such as sub, aud, iat, exp, etc.
    },
    "uid": "<UID>"
  }
}
```

Given the information above, your best bet to get the `uid` of the user who triggered the event is to do the following:

```
exports.someFunction = functions.database.ref('/some/path')
  .onWrite(event => {
    var isAdmin = event.auth.admin;
    var uid = event.auth.variable ? event.auth.variable.uid : null;

    // ...
});
```

Just note that in the code above, `uid` would be `null` even if `isAdmin` is `true`. Your exact code depends on your use case.

**WARNING:** This is currently undocumented behavior, so I'll give my usual caveat of "undocumented features may be changed at any point in the future without notice and even in non-major releases."

Comment: Any reason why there isn't a public API for this?  Seems like a reasonable use case (we're exploring FB as a backend and this was a major outstanding question).

Comment: Any indications that this will change or stay? This is ideal for my use case but I don't want to use it if could still change.

Comment: Added a bug/request to document this and make it an official public API https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/133

Comment: In case somebody else is wondering this is the entire object when the event.auth is not from admin: https://pastebin.com/CgyivDRm

Comment: Looks like the syntax has changed with the release of v1.0.0, and it's now documented: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: @taykay08 - Thanks! I've updated my answer to include this new information.