# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Knowing which user has written the data in onWrite

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a simple messaging app. In the process, I want to use firebase's cloud function feature for functions that should not be carried out client-side for the sake of security.

Many of the functions I want to be called whenever the user wants. The way I'm trying to do it now is by having clients push little 'function request' objects under a single parent so that the onWrite function will fire off and I can parse the request object to execute the function (The reason I'm not using http functions is because I want some way to securely know which user has made the request).

The problem is I can't find a way in firebase's documentation to know which user wrote the data.

in index.js I have

```
exports.requestFunction = functions.database.ref('/function-
requests/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
// Parse event.data.val() for things like the function name and its
// parameters. Then actually call the function.
// Ideally I would also be able to parse event somehow to find the user
// who saved the data.
});
```

Please note that I have considered including the user id as a parameter, but that's too unsafe as any user can pretend to be another user by giving a different uid.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [Firebase Database Rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) that only allows the user to write their own user id in a specific field, then pass it up as a parameter.

ex.

```
"user": {
  ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.  First, you can make the UID part of the database write path, the use a security rule to ensure that only an authenticated rule can write to that path.  Consider the Database trigger wildcard path `"/commands/{uid}/{pushid}"` along with the following security rule:

```
"commands": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Only an authenticated user can effectively write to their own area of the database under /commands/{uid}.  You can grab the matched UID wildcard in the function like this: `const uid = event.params.uid`

Consider watching [my talk at Google I/O 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g) where I use this strategy to build a turn-based game.

You can also ask the database trigger event the UID that generated the write, as described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750060/getting-the-user-info-userrecord-from-a-database-trigger-in-the-firebase-cloud), though it is not documented (or supported).

Answer (score 0):

First you can read more about security rules in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/), (different with other links "security/database")

Make sure in the data that you want to save to the database contains field for example `"user_id"`, this field will be checked with the `auth.uid` whether it's same or not.

make your database rule like this :

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   "function-requests": {
      "$pushId" :{
          ".write": "newData.child('user_id').val() == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can proceed your cloud function without worries