# Firebase database functions onWrite/Create/Delete user UID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is is possible to get the user UID of the user who wrote/updated/deleted data from the database?

Comment: Are you trying to determine this within Cloud Functions? Or somewhere else? It'll probably be easier to help if you give some more context, or better yet, the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're trying to determine if from Cloud Functions, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750060/getting-the-user-id-from-a-database-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `Firebase authentication` you can get the `uid` of the authenticated user using the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
}
```

On the other hand, you need to know that Firebase does not store meta-data or other informations regarding write operation. To achieve this, you need to create your own mechanism.

In your case, when a user creates a record, store his uid on a location from where you can query for that particular uid and use it for what you want.

In case you are trying to determine this within Cloud Functions i recomand you take a look at [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) and at jacobawenger's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750060/getting-the-user-id-from-a-database-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Comment: I think OP may be trying to determine the user from Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen! I have just edited my answer.

Comment: If my guess at OP's intent is correct, we should close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, You're right Frank. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yep you are right, should be closed.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo