# Cloud Functions: Firestore Promise chain

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have Firestore database. Colletions simple:

> "tasks/{taskId}": {
>   "ownerUid": "task owner Firebase Uid", 
>   "whoDidUids": ["user_1_FirebaseUid","user_2_FirebaseUid"]
>   }
>
> "users/{userUid}": {"fcm_token": "firestore cloud messaging token"}

Want just to write simple Cloud Function which will be triggered on:

```
exports.taskDoneNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('tasks/{taskId}')
    .onUpdate((event) => {

       //when another user did task it means 
       //userUid will be added to task.whoDidUids array
       //I want to get task owner fcmToken and send him
       // simple notification like "your task done by someone!"
    });
```

I'am new to js syntax, writing on Kotlin for Android.
Please provide me some examples how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar.

Unfortunately the "auth" object where you would get the UserId from is no yet implemented in Firestore Database Triggers. :(

See here:

[Question 46912161](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912161/getting-the-user-id-from-a-firestore-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase/47558027#47558027)