# Cloud Firestore, retrieve current user

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried everything, well except the right way, to retrieve the currentUser(doc) from users collections in Cloud Firestore.

Such as vue-firestore:

this.$binding("user", firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(this.firebase.auth().currentUser))

Thanks so much for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the user from a collection you would need the signed in user's UID. The Auth() Object is not yet implemented in "Firestore database triggers". (It is implemented for firebase RTD)

See my answer here:

[Getting the user id from a Firestore Trigger in Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912161/getting-the-user-id-from-a-firestore-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase/47558027#47558027)

Answer (score 0):

since the user is a document in cloud firestore , then you could retrieve the single document this way according the documentatin 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

from the documentation :-

> The following example shows how to retrieve the contents of a single document using get():

```
    var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

in your case you can do the following :-

```
     const db = firebase.firestore()

      db.collection('users')
     .doc('currentUserID') // change to the current user id 
     .get().then((user)=>{
         if(user.exists){
             // now you can do something with user
             console.log(user.data())
         }
     })
```