# how to print current user detail from firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, razorpay

i have problem like simply think i make two transaction from different users then there will be module like receipt where i need to display transaction detail of current user transaction.if one user complete the transaction and then at the next suppose he does not open receipt module and the second user complete transaction next and i do group by from razor-pay payment id so the next second user open receipt module he gets perfect result but at the next the first user will open receipt module and he gets transaction detail about other not for his transaction detail..so what i need to do for displaying specific user transaction details.

`Query query = firebasefirestore.collection("UserDataR").orderBy("razorPayId").limitToLast(1);`

Database Structure
[image]

Comment: Please post database structure

Comment: @Ashish can u see above i mentioned that when you say..

Comment: Isn't there any timing provided so you can query on depend timing ?

Comment: @Ashish No there are nothing like added timing or such anything..i need to print current user transaction details..Here timing and date is rquired?

Comment: @Ashish have u any solution for this?

Comment: How you differentiate user ?

Comment: through the database auto generated key id...@Ashish

Comment: @Ashish any solution??

Comment: @Ashish have u any solution for this??

Comment: it's not possible to get such info directly instead please try to contact me on other platform or social media. Answer is not small for your problem

Comment: @Ashish please share your instagram id

Comment: @Ashish How can i connect with you?

Comment: i've provided links please contact there

Comment: sry i have no twitter or linkedin bcz i'm student so u can only help me by stackoverflow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Firestore, retrieve current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798975/cloud-firestore-retrieve-current-user)

Comment: @v1gnus No ! i still not get any perfect answer