# Firebase Cloud Firestore trigger context.auth is always null

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase and Cloud Firestore to build a group app, where users should be able to create groups and add members to it.

As a user creates a group, I want a cloud trigger to add that user to the group's member list after the group has been created. The trigger looks like this:

```
exports.addCreatorAsAdmin = firestore
  .document('groups/{group}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    if (context.auth == null) { return unauthorizedError() }
    const path = `groups/${context.params.group}/members/${context.auth.uid}`;
    return db.doc(path).create({});
  });
```

As I run the app, sign in the user and create a team, the function is correctly triggered. However, I always hit the unauthorized error, which means that `context.auth` is null.

TLDR; the user is correctly signed in, but the trigger is unauthorized. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46912161 (as found by https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+cloud+functions+firestore+trigger+get+user)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloud Firestore currently doesn't support `context.auth` for determining which user made the change.  As you can see from the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#optional-auth):

> **This field is only populated for Realtime Database triggers and
>   Callable functions.** For an unauthenticated user, this field is null.
>   For Firebase admin users and event types that do not provide user
>   information, this field does not exist.

What you can do instead is have the user write their UID into a field of the document, and validate that with security rules as described in [this post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-per-user-permissions-for-cloud-firestore-be67ee8edc4a).

Comment: Thank you, I missed that part! I guess I'll just add a "members" array with that user in the creation payload instead.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if you have a moment.

Comment: Uhm, I thought I did, but it seems like I only upvoted it. Fixed!