# Tell if document is deleted by Cloud Function or by Authenticated user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In an onDelete trigger, can I determine whether the Firestore document was deleted by a User vs. a Cloud function?

I have a document that may be deleted by either directly by a user or through a callable cloud function, and I want different logic depending on the scenario.

e.g.

```
exports.example = functions.firestore.document('...').onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
    const isUserDelete = context.auth !== undefined; 
    if (isUserDelete){
        //Do something
        return;
    } else {
        //Do something else
        return;
    }
```

I know this information is supposed to be in the context argument, but I cannot make it work.

According to the docs on **context.auth**:

"For Firebase admin users and event types that do not provide user information, this field does not exist."

However every method to check if context.auth exist that I've tried has failed:

```
context.auth === undefined;
context.hasOwnProperty(auth)
context.auth === null;
context.auth === true
context.auth === {};
```

These do not separate cloud function deletes from user deletes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In an onDelete trigger, can I determine whether the Firestore document was deleted by a User vs. a Cloud function?

No, it's not possible, unless you also put some data into the document that identifies the source of the update.  For deletes, this obviously poses a problem, since the document isn't going to have any new data associated with it.

For Firestore triggers, `context.auth` is never populated in any circumstance.

See also:

- [Getting the user id from a Firestore Trigger in Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912161/getting-the-user-id-from-a-firestore-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
- [Include `context.auth` for Firestore triggers](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/300)