# Firebase Cloud Functions EventContext.auth (Migration Guide)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I followed along the "Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions Migration Guide"
and had problems integrating the new properties to get the user auth information after uploading a file to the cloud storage.

```
exports.processFile = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object, context) => {
  console.log('Uploaded ', object, context);
});
```

As it can be seen in the snippet above, I have switched to the onFinalize method. The object parameter contains all information regrading the uploaded file. However the context is empty.

I am wondering how to retrieve the user's auth token with the new properties `EventContext.auth` as shown here. [New properties for user auth information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No information about the user that write the file to storage is passed to your Cloud Function automatically. If you need such information, it is common to pass it into the path of the file.

The properties described in the [migration documentation for realtime database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#new_properties_for_user_auth_information) only apply to Cloud Functions that are triggered from the Realtime Database. They do not apply to Storage triggers.

Comment: Alright thanks for making that clear. I just assumed this would work with every triggered cloud function.

Comment: It is a separate task for each event provider. But it's also useful for each provider, so makes a great [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).