# Firebase function context.auth and context.authType undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am diving into Firebase functions (server-side), and having trouble grabbing the authentication information from within the function.  In it's simplest form, my index.ts that is getting deployed to Firebase functions looks like this :

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();
export const createOrganization = functions.firestore.document("Organizations/{organizationId}").
    onCreate((snap, context) => {
      console.log(context)
});
```

I can see from Firebase's logging that this function is indeed getting called, and the context that gets logged looks something like this :

```
{ eventId: 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX',
  timestamp: '2018-04-13T21:37:33.349247Z',
  eventType: 'google.firestore.document.write',
  resource: 
  { service: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
     name: 'projects/XXXX/databases/(default)/documents/Organizations/XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  },
  params: { organizationId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' } 
}
```

I would expect from the documentation that the context parameter would also include properties called "authType" and "auth" that contain information about the user who is making the request.  However, after trying all sorts of things, context.authType and context.auth are always undefined.

I have tried this both as an authorized user and unauthorized user with no changes.

Any help figuring out why context.authType and context.auth are not populated would be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: It seems the context auth information is only available for [Realtime Database events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#realtime-database). See this answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49723193/4815718

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Auth information is only given for Firebase products that provide auth information to Cloud Functions for each triggered event.  Currently, only Realtime Database supports this.  Firestore support is being worked on.  In theory, Cloud Storage could provide support as well.

It's inconsistent because each event provider in Cloud Functions for Firebase is driven by different teams, each with different implementations and priorities.

Comment: Ah, that is a major bummer, but I guess it would explain it.  Thank you!

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: @zavtra It is still true.

Comment: @DougStevenson is there any change in this area yet or can you give some more info? Im building something that would be so much easier if i could get the auth context for who deleted it and so on (using firestore)

Comment: @Swift No changes.  If it ever changes, you will see it mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @DougStevenson are there any changes in this scenario. I am still getting undefined in auth and authType.

Comment: this is somewhat important, I am surprised, it's not in yet?

Comment: It's really shocking!, this is really a core peace!