# Securely saving data in Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

The Firestore documentation [shows](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query) [examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access) of how to secure data using Firestore security rules based on the `request.auth.uid` field. These typically look something like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /stories/{storyid} {
      // Only the authenticated user who authored the document can read or write
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
    }
  }
}
```

That makes perfect sense.

What I don't understand (and doesn't appear to be shown anywhere) is how to set the `resource.data.author` field securely.

Obviously that can't just be based from the client because then any authenticated user can tamper with the request to set their author to any value.

I thought maybe we are supposed to use CloudFunctions to set that field but [at the moment this doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825566/firebase-function-context-auth-and-context-authtype-undefined/49827227#49827227).

The impact of this is pretty clear in the [role based access example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access):

```
{
  user: "alice",
  content: "I think this is a great story!"
}
```

Surely there must be a tamper-proof way to set the user field there - otherwise any user can make their comments appear to be from anyone else. This seems bad.

In the Firestore example web app, it seems to set the [userId field on the client side](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/firestore/scripts/FriendlyEats.View.js#L164) and I think it is doing [the same in the Android version](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/1791a58ffe13f364dfc1b39356ca0ec8fbf0d7f5/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/fireeats/RatingDialogFragment.java#L73).

What am I missing?

Edit: as @imjared points out this rule implies that 'alice' in `user: "alice"` is actually a uid, so I think this is safe.

I knew I was missing something.

```
match /comments/{comment} {
  allow read: if isOneOfRoles(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/$(story)),
                              ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter', 'reader']);
  allow create: if isOneOfRoles(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/$(story)),
                                ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter'])
                && request.resource.data.user == request.auth.uid;
```

Comment: Let's say they "tamper with the request to set their author to any value." If they do, then the changed author value it won't match their `request.auth.uid`, will it?

Comment: I don't think the user field (user: "alice") is a uid is it?

Comment: Oh, maybe it is! I think that could make sense.

Answer (score 0):

When the user writes a document to Firebase, they can indeed send any value for the `author` field they want. But there's no way for them to set `request.auth.uid`. This last bit in crucial to ensure all (read and write) access is authorized.

The first rules snippet you shared actually has two rules, and it might be easier to separate them out for a moment:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
```

The `write` rule only allows the operation when the `author` specific in the request is the same as the `request.auth.uid`. Since `request.auth.uid` can't be spoofed, and the value of `author` will only be accepted if it is the same, the write operation is only allowed if the `author` field is that of the currently authenticated user.

In fact, that latter rule is more regularly written as:

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author;
```

The difference when using `request` is that it explicitly refers to the document (`resource`) that is in the `write` request. The result is the same here whether we use `resource` or `request.resource`, but I find it easier to see how security works when thinking of the `request` here.

Comment: This makes sense. However, in that first rule, the way it is written is there anything stopping a user setting the author of one of their own stories with another author?

Comment: If anyone can set anyone else's UID as the author, what security are you looking for?

Comment: I don't think someone should be be able to set the author of their own stories to someone else. Imagine the comments on this answer were stored in Firebase, and I wanted to change the author of the first comment (mine) to you. Won't it check my uid == currentdata.author, and allow the update?

Comment: Aha... so you want it to be unmodifiable? In that case add a check for `request.resource.data.author == resource.data.author`.

Comment: I don't want this to seem unreasonable, but doesn't a security rule which lets someone modify authorship seem not-super-secure? The comment on that rule says "Only the authenticated user who authored the document can read or write", which would no longer be true after such a modification.

Comment: Give it a try, see if it does what the comment says. If it doesn't, try the change I proposed.