# Firebase Callable Function context is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have written a firebase Http callable cloud function based on the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs from the firebase team. However, my function is unable to verify the custom claims on a user (me) as 'context.auth' is undefined

I've updated firebase, firebase tools, firebase-functions and admin SDK to the latest versions.

My functions/Index.ts file

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp()

export const addAdmin = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (context.auth.token.admin !== true) {
        return {
            error: 'Request not authorized'
        };
    }
    const uid = data.uid
    return grantAdminRole(uid).then(() => {
        return {
            result: `Request fulfilled!`
        }
    })
})

async function grantAdminRole(uid: string): Promise<void> {
    const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    if (user.customClaims && (user.customClaims as any).admin === true) {
        console.log('already admin')
        return;
    }
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        admin: true,
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('made admin');
    })
}
```

My app.component.ts code

```
makeAdmin() {
    var addAdmin = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addAdmin');
    addAdmin({ uid: '[MY-USER-ID]' }).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

The function executes well if I don't try to access 'context' and I can add a custom claim to this user. However if I try to access context.auth I find the error:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that `context.auth` doesn't have a value.  As you can see from the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#.auth), `auth` will be null if there is no authenticated user making the request.  This suggests to me that your client app does not have a signed-in user at the time of the request to the callable function, so make sure that is the case before invoking the function.  If you allow the case where a callable function can be invoked without a signed in user, you will need to check for that case in your function code by checking `context.auth` before doing work on behalf of that user.

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you so much for your feedback. I've been sending the request from my client as a logged-in user (myself) and I've tried with other logged in user accounts. I'm using cloud Firestore, I've read from other questions you've answered (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825566/firebase-function-context-auth-and-context-authtype-undefined?rq=1) that I might be getting this unpopulated context.auth because I'm using firestore rather than RTDB. Do you think this is the case?

Comment: No, the database doesn't matter here.  context.auth will have the correct auth info from a client invoking the callable with the Firebase SDK.  If this doesn't work the way you expect, and you have a 100% reproducible sample that anyone can run, you should file a bug with Firebase report.  But I don't think the SDK is broken in any way, as this is one of its core features.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Doug, your answer helped to direct me onto an eventual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't properly integrating AngularFire Functions. I found the solution to my problem here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md

I changed my client component code to the following:

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

//other component code

makeAdmin() {
    const callable = this.fns.httpsCallable('addAdmin');
    this.data$ = callable({ uid: '[USERID]' })
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log({ resp });
      }, err => {
        console.error({ err });
      });
  }
```