# How to get current user ID in Firebase Cloud Functions with Firestore trigger?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Our users are using custom token authentication. When logging in to our app, the following code is executed:

`firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`

where `token` is created using `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth#createCustomToken` from Firebase Admin, passing user id.

Then a user is adding some documents in Firestore, using for example:

```
firebase.firestore()
.collection('users')
.document('someId')
.set({
  some: 'data'
})
```

I have a Firebase Cloud Function listening to changes in Firestore documents:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Listen for updates to any `user` document.
exports.testCloudFunction = functions.firestore
.document('users/{documentId}')
.onWrite((event) => {
  // print the id here
});
```

How can I print the uid of the logged in user that created the Firestore document which triggered my function?

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750880/1498594) to similar question about Realtime Database triggered function it's said to use `event.auth` object, but in my function its value is `undefined` (may it be an error in my code or is it supposed to be empty?)

Comment: This is currently not possible with Firestore.  The team is aware this is in demand.  If you would like to file a feature request, that adds weight to the request.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson ah that's too bad, thanks for the response. I filed a feature request.