# How to get data from wildcard in firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Assuming that I trigger events on the following `ref('/users/{userId}/items/{newItem}')`
I want to get a value from inside the  wildcard `userId`

I have tried `var token = event.params.userId.token` but it return to be undefined

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your code snippet only `event.params.userId` will be defined. There is no magic lookup of the user with that ID happening. If you want to get the user object of the user that triggered the function, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750060/getting-the-user-id-from-a-database-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried this snippet of code and it worked just fine: ` return admin
    .database()
    .ref(`/users/${userId}/token`)
    .once('value')
    .then(data => {
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(data.val(), payload);
});` where I triggered a single value for the wildcard userId to get its token

Comment: That snippet looks up the token in the database based on the `userId`. But you can't just read the token by doing `event.params.userId.token`, that `token` property simply isn't available on a parameter from the path that triggered the function.

Answer (score 6):

In firestore you can use this.

```
exports.getUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
        let userId = context.params.userId;
        //...
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

`Token` is not a parameter returned automatically from `trigger` events. 
In trigger wild cards only parameters corresponding directly to the wildcard are returned. So You need to do the following if you want to use the

```
var userId = event.params.userId
```

And then inside the function you can make another `Promise`

```
return admin.database().ref(/users/userId/token).once('value').then(data => { 
//do something here
 })
```

This will help you get the token. Or if you want to do it in one step, you can try the following with userID as wild card.

```
return admin.database().ref(/users/{userId}/token).once('value').then(data => { 
    //do something here
     })
```

But here you will receive multiple tokens and then you will have to iterate through the children to decide which `userId` is of relevance to you

Answer (score 1):

You can find wildcard values like this

```js
wildCardValue = context.params.wildCardName
```